# Check if it's possible to divide sequence into k non-intersecting subsections with odd sums

Tags: python, algorithm, sequence

*Subtractor is a set of consecutive elements.

I created this algorithm, but it doesn't work for 4 test. I don't know where is a mistake

```
n, k = map(int, input().split())
num = [int(i) % 2 for i in input().split()]
if (k - sum(num)) % 2 == 0:
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

Comment: It fails when you don't have enough odd numbers in the input: you also need `sum(num) >= k`. For example k=2 and input [2] fails.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can split a sequence into `k` subsequences each with odd sums if and only if the number of odd numbers is `k` plus a non-negative even number. Your code tests whether the number of odd numbers is `k` plus any (positive, zero or negative) even number.

Try this:

```
n, k = map(int, input().split())
odds = sum(int(i) % 2 for i in input().split())
if odds >= k && (odds - k) % 2 == 0:
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```